# How do I Split string only at last occurrence of special character and use both sides after split

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, string, split

I want to split a string only at last occurrence of special character.

I try to parse a name of a tab from browser, so my initial string looks for example like this:

> Untitled - Google Chrome

That is easy to solve as there is a Split function. Here is my implementation:

```
var pageparts= Regex.Split(inputWindow.ToString(), " - ");
InsertWindowName(pageparts[0].ToString(), pageparts[1].ToString());//method to save string into separate columns in DB
```

This works, but problem occurs, when I get a page like this:

> SQL injection - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia - Mozilla Firefox

Here are two dashes, which means, that after split is done, there are 3 separate strings in array and if I would continue normally, database would contain in first column value "SQL injection" and in second column value "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia". Last value will be completely left out.

What I want is that first column in database will have value:
SQL injection - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia" and second column will have: 
"Mozilla Firefox". Is that somehow possible?

I tried to use a Split(" - ").Last() function (even LastOrDefault() too), but then I only got a last string. I need to get both side of the original string. Just separated by last dash.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am really sorry about that, will know it next time. Thank you for a link

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. It's not that big of a deal. And now, you know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `String.Substring` with `String.LastIndexOf`:

```
string str = "SQL injection - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia - Mozilla Firefox";
int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf('-');
if (lastIndex + 1 < str.Length)
{
    string firstPart = str.Substring(0, lastIndex);
    string secondPart = str.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
}
```

Create a extension method *(or a simple method)* to perform that operation and also add some error checking for `lastIndex`.

EDIT:

If you want to split on `" - "` *(space-space)* then use following to calculate `lastIndex`

```
string str = "FirstPart - Mozzila Firefox-somethingWithoutSpace";
string delimiter = " - ";
int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf(delimiter);
if (lastIndex + delimiter.Length < str.Length)
{
    string firstPart = str.Substring(0, lastIndex);
    string secondPart = str.Substring(lastIndex + delimiter.Length);
}
```

So for string like:

```
"FirstPart - Mozzila Firefox-somethingWithoutSpace"
```

Output would be:

```
FirstPart 
Mozzila Firefox-somethingWithoutSpace
```

Comment: Your solution will not work for someting like : FirstPart - Mozzila Firefox-somethingWithoutSpace

Comment: @Seb, it would work perfectly for that example, since there won't be any need for `Trim` :)

Comment: @Clemens, *May be*, I didn't use it because OP is not using `Trim` on `split` result as well.

Comment: OP is using Regex.Split because he want to split using " - " as delimiter, not "-"

Comment: @Seb, from the question "I tried to use a Split(" - ").Last() function", I believe OP wants to split on `-` irrespective of the space.

Comment: @Seb, also even with a string like `FirstPart - Mozzila Firefox-somethingWithoutSpace` , OP can use the above code and replace `LastIndexOf(" - ")` *(using space-space)* and it would return `FirstPart` and `Mozzila Firefox-somethingWithoutSpace`

Comment: One minor improvement: use `" - "` as delimiter and `lastIndex + delimiter.Length` instead.   +1

Comment: @Habib Actually would it cause a problem, if there is a Tab Name for example like this: "Test-Tab-Name - last". What would be the result? I always no matter what want to catch just last occurence of a dash and I set spaces around the dash in delimiter only because I know the spaces are there like "TestTab - Mozilla Firefox" or "NextTab - Internet Explorer". Main goal is just to separate whatever is before "Mozilla Firefox" etc into one string. Is it a good idea or should I change it for something better?
EDIT: Is there a chance, there will be something after "Mozilla Firefox"?I never saw that

Comment: @Jacob, simply use `-` as delimiter and `Trim()` your results, this should work for space or no spaces. Because it seems like you are only concerned about splitting on dash, and you don't care about space.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this: 
`string delimiter = " - ";
                    int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf(delimiter);
                    if (lastIndex + delimiter.Length < str.Length)
                    {
                        string firstPart = str.Substring(0, lastIndex);
                        string secondPart = str.Substring(lastIndex + delimiter.Length);
                    }`
And it worked perfectly! Marking as answered, thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive me for my laziness ins this solution i'm sure there is a better approach but i will give you one solution proposal i'm assuming you are codding in C#.
First of all correct me if I get wrongly the question no matter what you just want to columns returned the first (all text even of it includes dashes but the last one) and last column (all the text after last dash) if it's ok. let's do it.
// I Only use split function when I want all data in separate variable (array position) in you case I assumed that you just want 2 values (if possible), so you can use substring.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string firstname = "";
        string lastName = "";
        string variablewithdata = "SQL injection - Wikipedia, -the free encyclopedia - Mozilla Firefox";

       // variablewithdata.LastIndexOf('-') = returns Integer corresponding to the last position of that character.
        //I suggest you validate if variablewithdata.LastIndexOf('-') is equal to -1 or not because if it don't found your character it returns -1 so if the value isn't -1 you can substring

        firstname = variablewithdata.Substring(0, (variablewithdata.LastIndexOf('-') - 1));
        lastName = variablewithdata.Substring(variablewithdata.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);

        Console.WriteLine("FirstColumn: {0} \nLastColumn:{1}",firstname,lastName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If it's not what you want can you explain me for example for "SQL injection - Wikipedia,- the free - encyclopedia - Mozilla Firefox" what's suppose to be returned?
Forgive me for unclean code i'm bored today.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about reassembling strings, you could use something like :

```
var pageparts= Regex.Split(inputWindow.ToString(), " - ");
var firstPart = string.Join(" - ", pageparts.Take(pageparts.Length - 1));
var secondPart = pageparts.Last()

InsertWindowName(firstPart, secondPart);
```

Comment: I dont care about reassembling. I only care about splitting that string and save both values to the database. How would I utilize code you provided? I don't understand, how does it work with code provided from me. Can you please explain it a bit better for me?